# PostgreSQL : avoid SUM over same values multiple times

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, sum

I've a student table and a table of scores in various subjects. I want to sum score1 & score2 for each student across all subjects and then add the bonus for each student.

```
CREATE TABLE student (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   name text NOT NULL,
   bonus integer NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE score (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  subject text NOT NULL,
  score1 integer NOT NULL,
  score2 integer NOT NULL,
  student_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT s_id FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student (id),
);
```

The query to join score1 & score2 looks like this:

```
SELECT st.name, sum(sc.score1 + sc.score2) as total
FROM student st
LEFT JOIN score sc ON sc.student_id = st.id
group by st.name
```

If I add `bonus` to this query i.e. `sum(sc.score1 + sc.score2 + st.bonus)`, it gets repeated for each student multiple times (depending on how many times student_id occurs in score table).

Do I have to use a subquery i.e. compute the sum of score1 & score2 first and then add that to bonus (see below) or is there a better way?

```
SELECT sq.name, sum(sq.bonus+sq.total) FROM
( SELECT st.bonus, st.name, sum(sc.score1 + sc.score2) as total
  FROM student st
  LEFT JOIN score sc ON sc.student_id = st.id
  group by st.name
) AS sq
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a subquery but you don't need to. Just don't sum the `bonus` and add it in the `GROUP BY` list.
Notice that you have to also add the `student.id`, even in your original query, in case you have 2 students with same name.
You probably also need `coalesce()` for students without any scores:

```
SELECT st.name, 
       coalesce(sum(sc.score1),0) + coalesce(sum(sc.score2),0) + st.bonus AS total
FROM student st
LEFT JOIN score sc ON sc.student_id = st.id
GROUP BY st.id, st.name, st.bonus ;
```

In newer versions of Postgres, you could use only the primary key of the `student` table in the group by:

```
SELECT st.name, 
       coalesce(sum(sc.score1),0) + coalesce(sum(sc.score2),0) + st.bonus AS total
FROM student st
LEFT JOIN score sc ON sc.student_id = st.id
GROUP BY st.id ;
```

If you want a subquery, this is one way:

```
SELECT st.name, 
       coalesce(sc.score, 0) + st.bonus AS total
FROM student st
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT student_id, sum(score1) + sum(score2) AS score
      FROM score 
      GROUP BY student_id
    ) AS sc ON sc.student_id = st.id ;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `SUM()` aggregates over all rows with identical values of those columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. Here score1 & score2 are aggregated independently and then the 3 values of score1_agg, score2_agg and bonus are added for each row.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Is there a difference between `sum(score1+score2)` vs `sum(score1)+sum(score2)` ?

Comment: Not really any difference (unless there are nulls).

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by sudjects or otherwise you get the sum multiplicated each time you add one more sudject:

```
SELECT st.name, sum(sc.score1 + sc.score2) as total
FROM student st
LEFT JOIN score sc ON sc.student_id = st.id
group by st.name,sc.subject
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think they want sum per subject. But sum per student. Plus, this won't solve the issue with `bonus`.